# How to determine the method signature in C# reflection with list of object parameters

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have a C# reflection question that I'm not sure how to achieve.

I need to allow access to string methods in an XML configuration file for a product I'm working on.

For example:

```
<someElement field="someField.Substring(5,10)">
```

I can gather the method - Substring - and the parameters - 5 and 10 easily enough.

If there is an overloaded method with the same number of parameters, but of different types, how will I know which one to use when I can't be sure of the input parameter types?

At the moment I can try to convert the parameters to the types in the signature and if they pass then perform that method. If they fail the conversion then I know for sure not to use that method. If two methods succeed then I'm lost.

The other option is to force in the configuration file the user to put the type before the parameter like:

```
<someElement field="someField.Substring(int 5, int 10)">
```

This is what I think I'll have to do unless I'm missing some aspect of reflection that would make this easier (I don't have much experience using reflection).

EDIT: The overall goal is to allow the professional services division of my company, who will be performing the deployments of the product for new customers, to be able to tweak the input given by the client to their requirements. For some clients my company will need to manipulate input data (in ways not known until configuring for the system for that client) based on a number of factors. This could be that a client has changed their data structure or format of data after the product was deployed. Or this could be due to on boarding multiple clients into a single installation where we need to differentiate two clients with similar names etc...

I need to create a way to handle a broad number of situations and I think this will offer the most flexibility.

Comment: afaik, method overload resolution is one of the more advanced alogrithms in a compiler, so I think your second approach would be easier, Or you can try some run-time compiling with roselyn, but I don't have experience with that. But maybe, if you explain the overall goal you are trying to achieve here, there maybe an overall better approach than writing code in your xml file.

Comment: Is it your intent to allow only a single method on a type as show in your example, or do need to evaluate complex expressions?  You may be better served by using an addin framework to perform the data transformation.

Comment: My intent is to allow all string methods to be available to the person deploying the product. Basically they need string manipulation abilities more so than complex evaluations.